# WebApi / AutoFac and an iDependencyResolver error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have got a DDD-layered application, so it contains both an Asp.Net MVC 4 project and an WebApi project (2 projects in the presentation layer).

Adding Autofac with Asp.Net MVC 4 = ok
Adding Autofac with Asp.Net WebApi = not ok

This is my global.asax.cs from my asp.net web api

```
var configuration = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Configure the container with the integration implementations.
// builder.ConfigureWebApi(configuration);
builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(configuration);

// Register API controllers using assembly scanning.
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

builder.RegisterType(typeof(UnitOfWork)).As(typeof(IUnitOfWork)).InstancePerLifetimeScope()
    .OnRelease(x => { ((IUnitOfWork)x).Commit(); });
builder.RegisterType(typeof(DatabaseFactory)).As(typeof(IDatabaseFactory)).InstancePerLifetimeScope().AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(UserRepository).Assembly).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository")).AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(SecurityService).Assembly).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service")).AsImplementedInterfaces();
var container = builder.Build();

// Set the dependency resolver implementation.
var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
configuration.ServiceResolver.SetResolver(resolver);
```

The error i'm seeing is : 
    Could not load type 'System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver' from assembly     'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Tried rewriting the part of code for 3 times, but it just doesn't seem to work.

Already found some links to some blogs, but mostly they contain a reference to `builder.ConfigureWebApi(configuration);` and that doesn't exist in the newer version.

Any thoughts on how I could solve this?

Comment: What is the error what you get? I don't see it in your post.

Comment: Any chance on getting your IControllerFactory implementation, since it doesn't appear that Autofac ships with one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to your resolver, you are going to need a controller factory, I don't have expereince creating a controller factory for autofac (my experience is with windsor), but it should be straight forward.  You want to use `configuration.DependancyResolver` like so:

```
configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

Once you have created your factory you can assign it:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(yourfactory);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a pre-release version of Web API because in the RTW version the dependency resolver is set through a property:

```
var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
```

Make sure you are the RTW version of Web API and the latest NuGet package for the Autofac integration:

`Install-Package Autofac.WebApi`